# Open web-page, get its contents and follow a link that is in there

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to use a scripting language(Javascript, PHP) to achieve the following task.

1)I need to open a new webpage, given a URL, in a different window.

2)Find in its contents a specific link and open it in the same window.

Is this possible with Javascript? If yes, how is this possible?

PS:The first link is dynamic so I can only to hit it once in order to open it and read it. I have noticed that if I open it and then read it,using get_contents for PHP, there are some differences in the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to open the page and find the link you need.

An example for find all links:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

The method 'find' has similar jQuery sintax.
And PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser have a good documentation an examples.

Hope this help!

Comment: I have done this but I need to get the contents, while at the same point opening the page in order to allow cookies to be stored in my local. If I do it this way, cookies won't be stored as far as I am concerned

Comment: Now I understood complety (I guess). The 'ugly' way to do this is to load a page in a frame (it can be hidden) and parse it using jQuery.

Comment: This cannot be achieved as I cannot read the contents of a webpage hosted from a different server